# Iterate over a list containing xts objects of unequal length

Tags: r, functional-programming, xts, lapply

I have a list containing time series data stored in `xts` format. The lists are of unequal lengths, and only a subset of the dates / rows intersect.

I wish to iterate over combinations of the lists with various functions -- for the case in point, let's just say i wish to find differences.

I am able to do this for each single combination, but am unable to get a higher order function working to iterate across the batch.

So, for example, each of the following work:

```
combn(c(1,2), 2, function(X) exData[[X[1]]] - exData[[X[2]]])
combn(c(1,3), 2, function(X) exData[[X[1]]] - exData[[X[2]]])
combn(c(2,3), 2, function(X) exData[[X[1]]] - exData[[X[2]]])
```

However, my attempt at a *higher-order* function fails:

```
combn(1:length(exData), 2, function(X) exData[[X[1]]] - exData[[X[2]]])
```

Instead it returns the error: `Error in combn(1:length(exData), 2, function(X) exData[[X[1]]] - exData[[X[2]]]) : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`.

I am not sure what this means ...

An example data set may be constructed as follows:

```
set.seed(1)
dtime <- seq(Sys.Date(), length.out = 20, by='day')
exData <- replicate(4, runif(sample(9:12, 1)), simplify=FALSE)
exData <- lapply(exData, 
                 function(x) xts(x, 
                                 order.by = sort(sample(dtime, 
                                                        length(x)))[1:length(x)]))
```

The salient point is that not all dates are in each `xts` object that's contained in the list, and that the lists are of unequal length. At this point, i'm using the `xts` object rules to control the application of the function -- though that might change later.

So what's the appropriate way of looping over each of the combinations? The combinations are given by each of the columns in the below:

```
combos <- combn(1:4, 2)
R> combos
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    2    2    3
[2,]    2    3    4    3    4    4
```

---

Note: in the real life case, each `xts` has multiple columns, and allowing for variety in the function that is applied to the two inputs is required.  With the help of @flodel, i made the following functions, which preserve the column names after the operation, and have the desired flexibility.

```
funDiffName <- function(XTS, loc, ff){
# takes a list of XTS objects, a location pair (from combn), and the function to apply
# preserves names following the application of ff
    ffxy <- ff(XTS[[loc[1]]], XTS[[loc[2]]])
    names(ffxy) <- paste0(names(XTS[[1]]), "x", names(XTS[[2]]))
    ffxy
}

SecPx_diff <- combn(1:(length(SecPx_l)), 2,
                    function(X) funDiffName(SecPx_l, X, `-`),
                    simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: Are you looking for differences in the rows with same time stamps?

Comment: @geektrader yes i am looking for the difference between the row with the same timestamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that R is trying to put the results into an array, but the pieces have different sizes... The solution is to request a list by adding `simplify = FALSE` to the `combn` call.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `cbind` them first. for `xts`,  `cbind` function binds the two xts by their index.

```
combn(1:length(exData), 2, function(X) {
        temp <- cbind(exData[[X[1]]], exData[[X[2]]])
        temp <- (temp[, 1] - temp[, 2])
        temp[!is.na(temp)]
    }, simplify = FALSE)
```